# Solutions of a quadratic equation and their range

Tags: geometry, derivatives, conic-sections, tangent-line, slope

> 1. Find the range of $m$ such that the equation $|x ^ 2 - 3x + 2| = mx$ has $4$ distinct real solutions $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, and $\delta$.

> 2. Express the value $s(m) = 1/\alpha ^ 2 + 1/\beta ^ 2 + 1/\gamma ^ 2 + 1/\delta ^ 2$ in terms of $m$.

> 3. When $m$ varies as in $(1.)$, find the range of $s(m)$.

This is a question from the Japanese government MEXT scholarship $2013$ paper.

**What I did so far:**

The range I found for $m$ is $0 < m < 3 - 2\sqrt{2}.$ I found it by finding the maximum slope of the tangent to the parabola $-(x^2 - 3x + 2)$ as it would be the limiting value for $m.$

I could solve the first part but cannot understand how to approach the $2$nd and $3$rd sub-question.
Please help me with some hints on how to approach the questions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Write the range of $m$ you found.

Comment: 0 < m < 3 - 2√2

Comment: @SahilDesai **EDIT** your post to include this extra info

Comment: Use [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Example).

Comment: Note that I read "maximum slope of the tangent to the upside-down parabola" as "focus on the upside-down parabola, find the tangent with the maximum slope, which would happen at the turning point". $\quad$ Given that you calculated the correct numerical answer, I believe you have the correct idea, but just didn't express it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions are
$$\alpha=\frac{3+m+\sqrt{D_1}}{2},\; \beta=\frac{3+m-\sqrt{D_1}}{2},\;\gamma=\frac{3-m+\sqrt{D_2}}{2},\;\delta=\frac{3-m-\sqrt{D_2}}{2},$$
where $D_1=m^2+6m+1>0$ and $D_2=m^2-6m+1>0.$

**HINT for question $2.$**

We obtain by straightforward computation $$\alpha\beta=2\quad \text{and}\quad \frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta}=\frac{3+m}{2}.$$
Then $$\frac{1}{\alpha^2}+\frac{1}{\beta^2}=\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta}\right)^2-1$$

Analogous approach gives $\left(\frac{1}{\gamma^2}+\frac{1}{\delta^2}\right)$ in terms of $m.$